# Unable to aggregate the SCDF logs of different tasks

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have SCDF 2.5.1 and would like to run the composed task runner with many tasks t1,t2..tn and want all the logs from t1,t2,t3..tn along with SCDF server logs and composed task runner to be written in same file to provided location instead of writing in temp directory.

I tried using inheritLogging=true while launching the task. It is writing all the logs on console which I am concatenating to a file at provided location but I still see that It is also creating the specific log files for each s.c. tasks running, in windows temp directory. Is there any other ways to deal with this?

PS- I don't want new logs files created for each tasks in temp directory once I have allowed inheritLogging=true and let SCDF write on console all the logs(SCDF logs+ s.c.tasks logs) which I can further push to a file at provided location. Please advise.

Comment: The use of `inheritLogging` suggests that you are using `local` SCDF. Since the `local` SCDF is intended for development purposes only, you would see the outcome of what you describe above. To answer your question, currently, I don't think it is possible to do that. Hence, if you think it would be a good addition, feel free to contribute and submit a PR: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local

Comment: @IlayaperumalGopinathan how could I achieve the same in kube8 if I have to aggregate all the logs together? Will it create separate flog files for each tasks and separate logs for SCDF? Please advise.